# Angular JS pass data to $http a global error handler

Tags: angularjs

I have a global error handler function for $http request.

```
var errorHandler = function (err) {
    // log the error
    return {status: err.status, data: {result: -1}}
}

var get = function (url) {
    var i = 1      // I have a temp variable here, and want to pass it to errorHandler

    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: ***,
        timeout: 5000,
    }).then(function (response) {
        // do some thing
        return response
    }, errorHandler)
}
```

How can I pass the variable i to errorHandler?
I know I can do this:

```
var get = function (url) {
    var i = 1      // I have a temp variable here, and want to pass it to errorHandler
return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: ***,
    timeout: 5000,
}).then(function (response) {
    // do some thing
    return response
}, function (err) {
    // log the error
    console.log('i', i)   // access i
    return {status: err.status, data: {result: -1}}
    })
}
```

But if I want use a global errorHandler, what should I do?

==============

Update:

According to Leandro Zubrezki's answer, we can make it in this way:

```
var errorHandler = function (err, i) {
    // log the error
    return {status: err.status, data: {result: -1}}
}

var get = function (url) {
    var i = 1      // I have a temp variable here, and want to pass it to errorHandler

    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: ***,
        timeout: 5000,
    }).then(function (response) {
        // do some thing
        return response
    }, function(error){
        errorHandler(error, i)
    })
}
```

This is a stupid question from newbie. :)

Comment: all you wanna do is common method for error handling .. if you only need i for this page or business then how come it'll become common ?? if you say i may be pass sometime value then try like this `errorHandler (err,{i:i});`  catch add a value parameter in that method

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi, can you give me a sample, I have tried your method, it can not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
function(error) {
     errorHandler(error, i);
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of why this solves the OP's problem. Help others to understand.